# Как переводить машинные команды в код Assembler?

Tags: ассемблер

Подскажите как переводить машинные команды в код Assembler.
Например, 00052CCE 2B D0, 2B - команда SUB, а как понять какие регистры вычитаются не понятно.
Я понял так: 
00052D07 83 C7 08  соответствует AND EDX, EAX
00052D43 39 1E соответствует CMP  EBX, ESI
00052D76 8B D3 соответствует MOV  ESP, EBX
00052DA1 83 C6 08 соответствует MOV  ECX, EAX

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding

Comment: [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm).